# Vectors to Priority_queue in STL c++

Tags: c++, vector, stl, priority-queue

How to convert a vector v to priority_queue pq?
Like we can do as-

```
for(int i=0;i<(int)v.size();i++) pq.push(v[i]);
```

But is it possible to keep it more short and concise?

Comment: Unrelated: Isn't it better to just use a proper type for `i`?

Comment: [A good C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) might be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
priority_queue<int>pq(begin(stones),end(stones));
```

Answer (score 3):

There are different [constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) of `std::priority_queue` to initialize a priority queue from another container, such as `std::vector`. You can also choose whether you want a max heap (default, or by using `std::less`) or a min heap (`std::greater`).

[Live on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8723c8aba3be924f)

Here I have used C++17's [class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) to simplify the declarations as much as possible.

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  auto print_pq = [](auto& pq) {
    for (std::cout << "pq : "; !pq.empty(); pq.pop()) {
      std::cout << pq.top() << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  };

  std::vector<int> init_list{1, 2, 3};
  {
    // max heap
    std::cout << "max heap: \n";
    std::priority_queue<int> max_heap_1{init_list.begin(), init_list.end()};
    print_pq(max_heap_1);

    std::priority_queue max_heap_2(std::less<int>(), init_list);
    print_pq(max_heap_2);
  }

  {
    // min heap
    std::cout << "min heap: \n";
    std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::greater<int>> min_heap_1{
        init_list.begin(), init_list.end()};
    print_pq(min_heap_1);

    std::priority_queue min_heap_2{init_list.begin(), init_list.end(),
                                   std::greater<int>()};
    print_pq(min_heap_2);

    std::priority_queue min_heap_3(std::greater<int>(), init_list);
    print_pq(min_heap_3);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use vector as the internal container (which is the default), then you can simply use the following constructor:

> ```
> template< class Alloc > 
> priority_queue( const Compare& compare, const Container& cont,
>                 const Alloc& alloc );
> ```

Otherwise, you can use the constructor that accepts a pair of iterators:

> ```
> template< class InputIt >
> priority_queue( InputIt first, InputIt last,
>                 const Compare& compare = Compare(),
>                 Container&& cont = Container() );
> ```